# Parent pom calling multiple builds on child with parameters

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml

My parent `pom` has multiple children and one of them packages `war` and the rest `jar`. The unusual circumstance is that the war child project should generate two wars that are almost identical minus some minor configuration settings.

The way I do it at the child level is:

```
mvn install -Dinst.name=inst1 -Drepl.val=val1
```

which creates a war named `inst1` that contains a properties file containing `val`.

When I run

```
mvn install -Dinst.name=inst2 -Drepl.val=val2
```

It creates `inst2.war` containing a properties file with the token replaced with `val2` etc.

How can I configure the parent pom to call two builds on this sub project and submit the parameters `inst.name` and `repl.val` through the pom configuration that I, in the above example, supply via command line?

Comment: You will not be able to do that with a single plugin execution. What exactly is the difference between the two WARs? Can't you build a single one which picks up its configuration from an external location at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two wars or two jars using single pom (but it not recommended as it violates the basic concept of maven: modularity) by two ways.

1. Using maven profiles. You can configure the configuration of the war plugin differently in the profile and enable it using -P argument when you call maven
2. Using two separate configuration of the war plugin. You can bind the war goal to the package lifecycle phase mulitiple times to generate multiple artefacts.